# how to combine lists together in a certain way (PYTHON)

Tags: python, list

I want to take two lists and merge them together.

```
list1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
list2 = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

Desired output:

```
[['1', 'one'],['2', 'two'],['3', 'three'],['four', 'four']]
```

I basically want to combine the elements of both lists in the order they start in their lists.
I know the format of the output might seem wonky and is just there for a visual of what i want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
list(zip(list1, list2))
```

output:

```
[('1', 'one'), ('2', 'two'), ('3', 'three'), ('4', 'four')]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
def comblist(list1,list2):
    if len(list1) == 1:
        return [list1 + list2]
    else:
        return [[list1[0]] + [list2[0]]]+ comblist(list1[1:],list2[1:])
```